# Add physical keyboard support for page up and page down to Flutter lists

Tags: windows, flutter, keyboard, scrollview

Since Flutter 2.0, there is support for desktop hardware keys, but widgets like scrollable_positioned_list don't support it.

I found the problem is if I set `primary` parameter of ScrollView to true, it will accept PageUp and PageDown of physical keyboard, but the problem is I need to set ScrollController too, which can't be set with `primary` at same time.

Any suggestion?

(I tested it on Windows and Mac)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out the release notes for Flutter 2.2? They added some corrections in relation to the PageUp and the PageDown through the physical keyboard.

Follow the link for the Flutter 2.2's announcement: https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-2-fd00c65e2039